Accessing container on port 3000 thru traefik + Docker-compose
I have a Next js application for api and Vuejs for frontend.
I am using Docker and Traefik.
I can successfully access the frontend container but when I try to access the api container using example.in I get refused to connect error in browser, but if i try to access it over port 3000 with example.in:3000 I am able to access the application.
I want to run the api without adding port to the url, how can this be achieved?
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: "traefik"
    image: traefik:v2.11
    command:
    - "--api.insecure=true"
    - "--providers.docker=true"

    # entrypoint
    - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{any:.+}`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
    ports: 
      - "80:80" 
        # Bind to port 80 externally
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
  frontend:
    image: frontend:latest

    working_dir: /app
    environment:  # Define environment variables
      - API_URL=http://example.in
    depends_on:
      - api
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`example.com`)" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=web"
    
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

  api:

    image: api:latest
    working_dir: /app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`example.in`)" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"


Why did you remove with your edit the config/yaml stuff?! You made your question worse.

yeah . i was adding indentation .. so added it now again

Is it on purpose that you have 2 different domains for ui/api? Does example.in point really to your docker host? "Connection refused" means usally that there is nothing listening on port 80/443. Either because no server is running on the ip the domains points to or firewall issue. Do bot domains point to the same ip address? On what ports do the ui/api container listening on?

yes the two different domain are on purpose one for api and one for frontend.
Also i have configured both this domains in /etc/host file on my local . The api run on port 3000 , if i run it using example.in:3000 then i can successfully access the api , but cant do the same without using port.

It's very strange that you can access the API on http://example.in:3000/ since nothing in your compose file maps anything to the host port 3000. The only host ports mapped are 80 and 8080. If you get a reply on host port 3000, it's from a service that isn't defined in your compose file. Did you also start the API using plain docker run?

i have a build image where i have expose port 3000 ,
in My dockerfile i have this Configuration
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn",  "start:prod"]

How are you starting up your stack? Are you using docker compose up?

yes using docker compose up

To run the api without adding port to the URL, it needs to be accessed over http = port 80 or https = port 443. For most other port numbers, like 3000, the port must be explicitly added to the URL, as described here.

Removing this line from the api: service should help:
    api:
      labels:
        # Remove this line:
        - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
        # ...or change it to:
        - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=80"


There are no networks in the compose file. Therefore all containers are on Dockers default bridge network and in the api image and/or Dockerfile there is EXPOSE 3000, which is why the api container can be accessed on http://example.in:3000/, bypassing Traefik.
a) create a new (external) network, by running this command in cli:
docker network create 000-traefik-proxy-extrn

b) in the compose file, add the networks part to each service:
    reverse-proxy:
        networks:
          - 000-traefik-proxy-extrn
          # Maybe not needed:
          - bridge

    frontend:
        networks:
          - 000-traefik-proxy-extrn

    api:
        networks:
          - 000-traefik-proxy-extrn

# In the end of the file, no indentation for `networks:`
networks:
  000-traefik-proxy-extrn:
    name: 000-traefik-proxy-extrn
    external: true

The frontend and api containers should only be on the same network as the Traefik container, if the intention is to only access them through Traefik.
PS. The network name starts with 000 for it to be first in alphabetical order. There was an issue when this network was not the first alphabetically, among several networks.

Close the firewall port 3000 if the api is not supposed to be contacted on that port. Best practice is to close all ports that are not explicitly needed, so open only for port 80 (better with secure 443) and 8080. If on Ubuntu and using ufw, that is not enough, since Docker will bypass ufw. A possible solution is https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker.


